# restrict codeigniter admin panel ip address

Tags: codeigniter

hi friends i want to restrict ip address for my codeignter php website backend at office only for security reason. any advice if someone has already done it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to using .htaccess, you can also restrict the access from PHP (although .htaccess solution is more robust):

```
$your_ip_address='123.123.123.123'; //change it to yours
if (!isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $your_ip_address) {
   exit();
}
```

Locate the `index.php` in the webroot folder, add the above codes to the top of the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The idea works, but 2nd line had a typo (extra closing parenthesis), should be:

`if ( ! isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $your_ip_address) {
   exit();
}`

Comment: @DrMarble Typo fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Apache, you could use a .htaccess file like..

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Create a file .htaccess in the directory you want to protect and place the above inside.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: That rule will deny the acces to anybody but local ip for everything in the site, isn't it? May be sagarmatha just want to deny access to the backend controllers.

Comment: there is no directory to protect in codeigniter php framework, it's a class that should be protected.

Comment: This denies everybody from everywhere in the website

Answer (score 1):

I did this by following salah's post in this thread: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/141775/

Basically, you create a folder called admin/ , copy the main CI index.php to it, and adjust.

Then, add a .htaccess to that folder. For my application, I only needed AuthType, but IP allow/deny should work fine as well.

I was using CI 1.7.2 at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way to do this

```
$current_ip = $this->input->ip_address();
$your_ip_address='127.0.0.1';

if($current_ip == $your_ip_address){
    echo 'something is wrong';
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to share my code for doing it, in case you are behind a CDN, and you want to use allow multiple IPS:

```
/**
 * return array value in key in case it exists and has value
 * @param array $arr
 * @param $key
 * @return bool|mixed
 */
function is($arr = array(), $key){
    if(isset($arr[$key]) && $arr[$key]){
        return $arr[$key];
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * this function return the actual client IP in case it is behind CDN
 * @return string
 */
function getClientIp() {
    $ipAddress = '';
    if (is($_SERVER, 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if (is($_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if (is($_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED')) {
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    } else if (is($_SERVER, 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if (is($_SERVER, 'HTTP_FORWARDED')) {
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    } else if (is($_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR')) {
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    } else {
        $ipAddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    }

    return $ipAddress;
}

/**
 * Allowed IPS
 */
$allowedIPSArr = array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '127.0.0.2',
);

if(!in_array(getClientIp(),$allowedIPSArr, true)){
// You might want to do some redirect here
    die();
}
```